# HTML not rendering with two conditions for rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch<any>(GetOptions1());
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch<any>(GetOption2());
}, []);

return ((state?.options1 && state?.options2) && (<>
    <div className="m-4">          
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-5">
                Options1
                <DropdownSelector
                    options={getOptions1()}
                    selection={Options1}
                    onChange={(options1: DropdownFlatOption[]) => {
                        setOptions1(options1.map(o => o.value));
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
                Options2
                <DropdownSelector
                    options={getOptions2()}
                    selection={Options2}
                    onChange={(options2: DropdownFlatOption[]) => {
                        setOptions2(options2.map(o => o.value));
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</>))
```

Whenever I remove one of the condition from state?.options1 && state?.options2 then it works fine but as soon as I put this condition back it fails silently. No error on browser console but still HTML not get rendered. Any other way to render dropdown post data is available?

Comment: The code snippet seems incomplete. Where did you define this state?

Comment: Probably because `state?.options1` is falsy, or `state?.options2` is falsy. What are the values of those two expressions when it fails? Add a `console.log(state?.options1, state?.options2)` before the `return` statement. What gets logged?

Comment: You probably want `state?.options1 || state?.options2`